# jquery each regexp href check some strings at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, href

people!

I have this:

```
$('.download_video a[href*="flv"]').each(function() {

        $( this ).addClass('videoCl');

});
```

I would like to perform many checks in a single code line like:

```
$('.download_video a[href*="flv|mpeg|ogg"]').each(function() {

        $( this ).addClass('videoCl');

});
```

I've realized flv|mpeg|ogg is not working. I think it is a matter of little detail...

Anyone could help me?

Tks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put multiple attribute selectors in a single selector. However, you can combine multiple selectors using comma:

```
$('.download_video')
    .find('a[href*=flv], a[href*=mpeg] a[href*=ogg]')
    .addClass('videoCl');
```

Notice that you don't need to use `.each` if you're doing the same operation to each element; jQuery automatically maps over the entire set.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $.fn.attrs = function () {
        var args = arguments[0];
        var elem = $(this);
        var map = $.map(arguments[1], function (v, k) {
            return ($("[" + args + "*=" + v + "]").is(elem) 
                    ? elem[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() 
                      + "[" + args + "*=" + v + "]" 
                    : null);
        });
        return $(map.toString());
    };

$(".download_video a")
.attrs("href", ["mpeg", "flv", "ogg"]).addClass("videoCl");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/834q1awc/